# Why JavaScript execute function after page load?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```js
$(document).ready(
        function(){
                $("#signout-container").hide();
});
  
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  $("#signout-container").show();
  $("#signin-container").hide();    }

function signOut() {
  auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    console.log('User signed out.');
    $("#signout-container").hide();
    $("#signin-container").show();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="googleLogin" id="signin-container">
         <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>    
</div>
<div class="googleLogout" id="signout-container">
    <h4 class="font"><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></h4>
</div>
```

After I click the div `signin-container`, every time I reload the page `index.jsp`, JavaScript function `onSignIn` run.

Why? Which parameter do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `onSignIn` in binded to `data-success` and not `onClick`. I honestly never used Google API myself but I guess, once you logged in your IDs are stored in session and every times you reload your page you log in again and Google API trigger `data-success`.